# Choose Your Own Adventure

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

Choose Your Own Adventure books are a form of interactive literature where the reader must
make decisions that affect the outcome of the story. At certain points in the story, the
reader has multiple options that can be chosen, each sending the reader to a different page
in the book.

For example, in a fantasy setting, one might have to decide on page 14 whether to venture
into a mysterious cave by "jumping" to page 22, or to explore the nearby forest by jumping
to page 8. These "jumps" can be expressed as pairs of page numbers, like so:

```
14 22
14 8
```

In most cases, there are many endings to the story but only a few good ones. The goal is to
navigate the story to reach a good ending.

**Task:**

Given a list of "jumps" for a given book, your task is to determine a route that will lead
to a specific ending. Since this is fairly easy, the true challenge is to do it in as few
characters as possible.

This is **code golf**.

**Sample input (where 1 is the start and 100 is the goal):**

```
1 10
10 5
10 13
5 12
5 19
13 15
12 20
15 100
```

**Sample output:**

```
1 10 13 15 100
```

**Sample input:**

```
15 2
1 4
2 12
1 9
3 1
1 15
9 3
12 64
4 10
2 6
80 100
5 10
6 24
12 80
6 150
120 9
150 120
```

**Sample output:**

```
1 15 2 12 80 100
```

**Notes:**

- The list of jumps will be input by the user, either from a file or stdin. You may choose whichever is most convenient.
- The input will contain 1 jump per line, with the origin and destination separated by a single space.
- The lines in the input are not guaranteed to be in any specific order.
- A successful path will start at page 1 and end at page 100.
- You may assume there is at least 1 path to the goal. You do not need to find all paths, nor do you need to find the shortest. Just find at least one.
- The smallest page number will be 1. There is no limit to the largest page number. (You can assume that it will fit in the range of an int.)
- Loops may exist. For example, the list may have jumps from page 5 to 10, 10 to 19, and 19 to 5.
- There may be dead-ends. That is, a destination page might not have anywhere to jump to.
- Conversely, there may be unreachable pages. That is, an origin page might not be the destination of any jumps.
- Not all page numbers between 1 and 100 are guaranteed to be used.
- Your output should consist of a valid route of page numbers, starting with 1 and ending at 100, separated by spaces.

Remember, this is code golf, so the shortest solution wins!

**EDIT:** Added another sample for testing.

Comment: Can we assume that there are no jumps from page 100?

Comment: Yes, you may assume that.

Comment: i have a feeling that something like lisp or alloy could accomplish this in very few chars, i will attempt it later when i get off work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Golfscript, <strike>58</strike> 57 chars

```
~]2/.,{:A{){=}+{0=}\+A\,\`{\+}+/}/]A+}*{)100=\0=1=*}?' '*
```

**Warning**: this is super-inefficient. It works by repeatedly squaring the adjacency matrix and then looking for a route; if there are `E` edges in the graph then it will find every path of length up to 2<sup>E</sup> (and the shorter ones it will find lots of times). It should give you a result for the first test case in a reasonable time, but if you want to try the second one make sure that you've got a few gigs of memory free and go for a long walk.

If you want a reasonably efficient solution then I offer at 67 chars:

```
~]2/:A,[1]]({A{{{?)}+1$\,,}%~!*},{({\-1==}+2$?\[+]+}/}*{100?)}?' '*
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could do matrix multiplication in Golfscript!

Comment: @migimaru, it's a Turing-powerful language, however many shortcomings its array handling may have.

Comment: That's true. I guess I just didn't expect to see adjacency matrices fit into such a small space ;)

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I tried running this with `cat input | ruby1.9 golfscript.rb peter.gs` and all that happened was my MacBook got really hot. How should I run it?

Comment: @Gareth, I did say it was super-inefficient. I think it should handle the first test case in a couple of minutes, but the second one will take a *lot* of time and a *lot* of memory.

Comment: @Peter Ah. Using the second one as a test was a mistake then. :-)

Comment: @Gareth, yep. When I killed it after half an hour, it was up to 2GB of memory. I'll make the warning a bit more explicit.

Comment: After seeing Gareth's experience, I didn't bother testing the first  solution, but the second one works and still seems pretty hard to beat at this point.

Answer (score 14):

### Python, <strike>232</strike> <strike>213</strike> <strike>157</strike> <strike>143</strike> <strike>135</strike> 132 chars (shortest path)

This implementation can handle all of the edge cases described (loops, dead ends, orphan pages etc.) and guarantees that it will find the shortest route to the ending. It is based on Djikstra's shortest path algorithm.

```
import sys
l=[k.split()for k in sys.stdin]
s={"100":"100"}
while"1"not in s:
 for i,j in l:
    if j in s:s[i]=i+" "+s[j]
print s["1"]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript:  189 Characters

This is a recursive solution that finds the shortest path through the adventure.

**Code-Golfed:**

```
a=prompt().split('\\n');b=0;while(!(d=c(b++,1)));function c(e,f,i,g){if(e>0)for(i=0;h=a[i++];){g=h.split(' ');if(g[0]==f){if(g[1]==100)return h;if(j=c(e-1,g[1]))return g[0]+' '+j}}}alert(d)
```

To test (**WARNING:  infinite loop for bad input!**):

1. Copy one of the following input strings (or use a similar format to choose your own choose your own adventure):

   - `1 10\n10 5\n10 13\n5 12\n5 19\n13 15\n12 20\n15 100`
   - `15 2\n1 4\n2 12\n1 9\n3 1\n1 15\n9 3\n12 64\n4 10\n2 6\n80 100\n5
     10\n6 24\n12 80\n6 150\n120 9\n150 120`
2. Paste that into the [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/nKEZW/)'s prompt.

**Formatted and Commented code:**

```
//Get Input from user
inputLines = prompt().split('\\n');

//Starting at 0, check for solutions with more moves
moves = 0;
while (!(solution = getSolution(moves++, 1)));

/**
 * Recursive function that returns the moves string or nothing if no
 * solution is available.
 *
 * @param numMoves - number of moves to check
 * @param startPage - the starting page to check
 * @param i - A counter.  Only included to make this a local variable.
 * @param line - The line being tested.  Only included to make this a local variable.
 */
function getSolution(numMoves, startPage, i, line) {
    //Only check for solutions if there are more than one moves left
    if (numMoves > 0) {
        //Iterate through all the lines
        for (i=0; text = inputLines[i++];) {
            line = text.split(' ');
            //If the line's start page matches the current start page
            if (line[0] == startPage) {
                //If the goal page is the to page return the step
                if (line[1] == 100) {
                    return text;
                }
                //If there is a solution in less moves from the to page, return that
                if (partialSolution = getSolution(numMoves - 1, line[1])) {
                    return line[0] + ' ' + partialSolution;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Output the solution
alert(solution);
```

To test (**WARNING:  infinite loop for bad input!**):

1. Copy one of the following input strings (or use a similar format to choose your own choose your own adventure):

   - `1 10\n10 5\n10 13\n5 12\n5 19\n13 15\n12 20\n15 100`
   - `15 2\n1 4\n2 12\n1 9\n3 1\n1 15\n9 3\n12 64\n4 10\n2 6\n80 100\n5
     10\n6 24\n12 80\n6 150\n120 9\n150 120`
2. Paste that into the [test fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/DVLdA)'s prompt.

Comment: Nice use of recursion here. I also like the trick of giving the function extra arguments just to limit the variables' scope :)

Comment: @migimaru:  Thanks!  A related side note:  This problem was a bugger to debug until I learned that JavaScript variables without the `var` keyword have global scope :)

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby 1.9, 98

```
j=$<.map &:split
f=->*p,c{c=='100'?abort(p*' '):j.map{|a,b|a==c&&!p.index(b)&&f[*p,b,b]}}
f[?1,?1]
```

Ungolfed:

```
$lines = $<.map &:split
def f (*path)
    if path[-1] == '100' # story is over
        abort path.join ' ' # print out the path and exit
    else
        # for each jump from the current page
        $lines.each do |from, to|
            if from == path[-1] && !path.include?(to) # avoid loops
                # jump to the second page in the line
                f *path, to
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Very nice use of the splat there.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 88 chars

basically a perlized version of Clueless' entry; pre-matches and post-matches are fun :)

```
@t=<>;%s=(100,100);until($s{1}){for(@t){chomp;/ /;$s{$`}="$` $s{$'}"if$s{$'}}}print$s{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - <del>239</del> <del>237</del> 236

```
import sys
global d
d={}
for i in sys.stdin:
 a,b=[int(c) for c in i.split(' ')]
 try: d[b]+=[a]
 except: d[b]=[a]
def f(x,h):
 j=h+[x]
 if x==1:
  print ''.join([str(a)+" " for a in j[::-1]])
  exit()
 for i in d[x]:
  f(i,j)
f(100,[])
```

unfortunately, this tail-recursive solution is vulnerable to loops in the "story"...

**Usage**: cat ./test0 | ./sol.py
Output for test case 1:

```
1 10 13 15 100
```

Output for test case 2:

```
1 15 2 12 80 100
```

Answer (score 0):

### Scala 2.9, <strike>260</strike> <strike>256</strike> <strike>254</strike> <strike>252</strike> <strike>248</strike> <strike>247</strike> <strike>241</strike> <strike>239</strike> <strike>234</strike> <strike>227</strike> <strike>225</strike> <strike>212</strike> 205 characters

```
object C extends App{var i=io.Source.stdin.getLines.toList.map(_.split(" "))
def m(c:String):String=(for(b<-i)yield if(b(1)==c)if(b(0)!="1")m(b(0))+" "+b(0)).filter(()!=).mkString
print(1+m("100")+" 100")}
```

Ungolfed:

```
object Choose extends App
{
    var input=io.Source.stdin.getLines.toList.map(_.split(" "))
    def findroute(current:String):String=
    (
        for(branch<-input)
        yield 
        if(branch(1)==current)
            if(branch(0)!="1")findroute(branch(0))+" "+branch(0)
    ).filter(()!=).mkString
    print(1+findroute("100")+" 100")
}
```

Usage:

Compile with `scalac filename` and run with `scala C`. Input is taken via `STDIN`.
To run on ideone.com, change `object C extends App` to `object Main extends Application` to run it as Scala 2.8.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP, <strike>166</strike> <strike>146</strike> 138 chars

```
$a[]=100;while(1<$c=$a[0])for($i=1;$i<$argc;$i++){list($p,$q)=explode(' ',$argv[$i]);if($q==$c)array_unshift($a,$p);}echo implode(' ',$a);
```

Ungolfed :

```
$a[]=100;
while(1<$c=$a[0])
    for($i=1;$i<$argc;$i++){
        list($p,$q)=explode(' ',$argv[$i]);
        if($q==$c)array_unshift($a,$p);
    }
echo implode(' ',$a);
```

Usage :

```
php golf.php "1 10" "10 5" "10 13" "5 12" "5 19" "13 15" "12 20" "15 100"
```

Comment: This doesn't produce any output for me when I run it from the command line in windows or on ideone.com?

Comment: It works on my computer (windows). I added a usage exemple. I can't get it works on ideone.com though

Comment: Ah...that explains it, I was trying to send input through `STDIN` rather than as arguments.

Comment: User [genesis φ](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/2600/genesis) proposed an edit to correct the character count. It might be worth putting a golfed version without whitespace before the ungolfed version, to meet people's expectations of the local convention.

Answer (score -1):

I would put all of them into a 2d array and search all items with multiple loop,  if they can reach the last item then I would collect related items in order into another results array, and from results I would choose an array which one is smaller.

EDIT => JAVA:I have also used recursive function, full code below;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Jumper {
    static int x = 0;
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> c = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();  
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       //Read from line and parse into array
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("list.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        String line = null; 
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){s.add(line);}
        c.add(new ArrayList<String>());
            //When you get all items forward to method
        checkPages(0, s,Integer.parseInt(s.get(0).split(" ")[0]),Integer.parseInt(s.get(s.size()-1).split(" ")[1]));
    }   

    public static void checkPages (int level,ArrayList<String> list,int from, int dest){
        if(level <= list.size()){           
            for(int i=level;i<list.size();i++){
                int a = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).split(" ")[0]);
                int b = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).split(" ")[1]);
                if(a == from){
                    c.get(x).add(list.get(i));
                    if(b==dest){
                        c.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                        x++;
                    }else{
                        checkPages(i, list, b,dest);
                        c.get(x).remove(list.get(i));
                    }
                }

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is code-golf, so you need to provide an implementation.

Comment: Hi Gareth, I should leave now I will add asap when I arrive to home.