# Shortest route through a one-way system

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

My home town, [Rhyl](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=rhyl&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x48652618418b2481:0xfce1c44350b2b6e1,Rhyl,+Denbighshire&gl=uk&ei=xBELT6mLBdC3hAe7pICxCQ&sa=X&oi=geocode_result&ct=title&resnum=3&ved=0CGIQ8gEwAg), has a one-way traffic system which seems to have been designed to keep people away from their destination for as long as possible. Your task, should you choose to attempt it, is to produce a program to give the shortest route through such a traffic system.

### Input

Input will be on `STDIN`, and will be a list of start and end points followed by a blank line followed by a list of queries, as follows:

```
A B
B A
B C
C D
D C

A D
C A
B A
```

Each road can only be travelled in the direction(s) given, so, in the above example the road A - B is a two way street whereas B - C is a one-way street from B to C. Travelling from C to B is prohibited.

Start and end points will all be represented by a single upper-case letter.

### Output

Output should be the shortest route (measured by number of points visited) from the given start point to the given end point for each query received. If no such route exists, output a blank line. If more than one shortest route exists, output the first when sorting all shortest routes lexicographically.

For the above example the output would be:

```
A B C D

B A
```

### Test Scripts

As before I'm providing tests for this task based on scripts written by [Joey](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15/joey) and [Ventero](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84/ventero):-

- [Bash](http://www.garethrogers.net/tests/oneway/test)
- [PowerShell](http://www.garethrogers.net/tests/oneway/test.ps1)

and also tests and expected output for anyone who can't use the above scripts

- [Plain text](http://www.garethrogers.net/tests/oneway/test.txt)

Usage: `./test [your program and its arguments]`

### Rewards

All answers which have obviously had some attempt at golfing that meet the spec and pass all the tests will get my upvote. The shortest working answer by 26/01/2012 will be accepted.

Comment: `output the first when sorting all shortest routes lexicographically` - So if `A B D` and `A C D` are both valid solutions, output `A B D` instead?

Comment: @GigaWatt Yes, that's right.

Comment: This is awfully close to a duplicate of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/3474/choose-your-own-adventure

Comment: @PeterTaylor Why didn't you raise that while it was in the question sandbox? What do you suggest? I could delete it while there are no answers on it, I suppose?

Comment: @Gareth, because for once there was activity on a few threads on meta at the same time, and I didn't notice that there was a new reply in the question sandbox. Deletion is one possibility; or you could extend it to weight the edges - we haven't had a directed Dijkstra question yet.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Fair enough. A rewrite to weight the edges would take a fair amount of time though, especially re-doing the tests.

Comment: D'oh! I forgot that one when I was looking for similar questions. Sorry, GigaWatt. There is none-the less a small difference that arises from the shortes path and lexical sorting conditions. I think it can stay, though as @Peter says weighting is always fun.

Comment: @dmckee Ok, I'll leave it as it is and accept that people may ignore it as a duplicate. I'll come up with a weighted graph question next time if no-one beats me to it.

Comment: test cases seem to have problem, in testcase#2, J->A->I is a path, while you marked "J B I" as the answer.

Comment: @Gajet Okay, fixed it. Doing it by hand is no match for getting a program to do it for you. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Haskell, <s>223</s> 207 characters

```
main=interact$unlines.f.break null.map words.lines
s%[f,t]=[[f]]#t where[]#_="";x#t|y@(_:_)<-[z|z<-x,last z==t]=unwords$minimum y|1<3=s&x#t
s&z=[x++[b]|x<-z,[a,b]<-s,last x==a,notElem b x];f(s,_:q)=map(s%)q
```

Answer (score 2):

### Python (2.x), <strike>382</strike> <strike>369</strike> <strike>358</strike> <strike>338</strike> <strike>323</strike> 318 characters

All tips and comments welcome!

```
import os;u=str.split;l=u(os.read(0,1e9),'\n')
p,g,c=l.index(''),{},map;o=g.setdefault
def f(g,s,e,q=[]):q=q+[s];y=([],[q])[s==e];[c(y.append,f(g,n,e,q))for n in set(o(s,[]))-set(q)];return y
for k,v in c(u,l[:p]):o(k,[]);g[k]+=v
for w,e in c(u,l[p+1:]):h=sorted(f(g,w,e));print''if not h else' '.join(min(h,key=len))
```

Should pass the tests in this form. Feed input via stdin, e.g. `python shortestroute.py < test.txt`.

Comment: Seems to fail query 2 of test 4. Returns `A B I J M` instead of `A B G J M`.

Comment: @Gareth: there was indeed a small bug considering lexographical sort of similar length solutions, should be fixed now...

Answer (score 1):

## C:<strike>450</strike>,<strike>437</strike>,<strike>404</strike>,390 characters

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
r[99][99],p[99],q[99],m[99],i,j,x,y,s;
char t[9],e[9999];
F(k)
{
    m[k]^s?r[p[k]=q[i]][k]?m[q[j++]=k]=s:0:0;
    if(++k<99)F(k);
}
f()
{
    F(0);
    if(++i^j)f();
}
P(o)
{
    if(p[o])P(p[o]);
    *t=m[o]^s?0:o;
    strcat(e,t);
}
w()
{
    gets(t);
    r[*t][t[2]]=*t?w():0;
}
W()
{
    gets(t);
    x=*t,x?y=t[j=2],s=x+y*99,m[q[t[2]=i=p[x]=0]=x]=s,f(),P(y),strcat(e,"\n"),W():0; 
}
main()
{
    w();
    W();
    puts(e);
}
```

Comment: `puts("\n")` prints two newlines.  `puts()` automatically adds an end-of-line terminator to the strings it prints.  To avoid that behavior, use `fputs(str, stdout)` or simply `printf(str)`.

Comment: Bends the rules slightly - should take all the input in one go and then output all the answers to the queries in one go. I'll +1 it because it works fine (and found mistakes in the tests), but I won't be able to accept it over a longer program that fully complies with the input/output requirements.

Comment: @Gareth: fixed. though, answer output should not be as longer than 9999 characters!